# How to display a custom input in a product template?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm in a product template. I am creating a product builder functionality. I need to display the input type text so that the user can enter their value and when ordering, this field will be displayed. Should this be done through a metafield or just enter the input onto the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need metafields. Instead, set your search engine upon the Line Item Properties, and from that, you'll find all you need to do this. It is all you need. Nothing more, nothing less. Once you discover how easy that is, you'll be glad they exist.